# JSON return [Object][Object]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, axios, redux-saga

I'm trying to get data from json file, but it always return [object][object]

Here is json file https://my-json-server.typicode.com/khanh21011999/demo/user

Here is request function to get data

```
export function requestGetUser() {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/khanh21011999/demo/user',
  });
}
```

Here is the method i use to get data

```
    function* loginSaga(action) {
        
            console.log('Saga is working')
            const getJson = yield call(requestGetUser) //same
            const getJsonData = JSON.stringify(getJson)
        
            const getJsonUsername = String(getJsonData.username)
            console.log('GetJson '+getJson)
            
        
            const getJsonPassword = String(getJsonData.password)
        
            if (String(action.data.username) === getJsonUsername) {
                if (String(action.data.password) === getJsonPassword) {
                    console.log('saga login success')
                    yield put({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'})
                    SaveToAsyncStorage(action.data)
                }
                else {
                    console.log('saga password fail')
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("saga user fail")
            }
    }
    export {loginSaga}
```

**It return like this**
[image]

Weird things is i use a online tutorial to get data, it work with that(data show in above image)

**worked method**

```
export function* handleGetUser(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGetUser);  //same
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(setUser(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**setUser**

```
export const setUser = (user) => ({
    type: actionList.SET_USER,
    user,
});
```

**GetUserInfo**

```
export const GetUserInfo = (user, password) => {
    return{
        type: actionList.GET_USER_INFO,
        data: {user, password}, //same??
    }
};
```

**Here is export function**

```
export function* watchSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_USER, handleGetUser);  //work
  yield takeLatest(GET_USER_INFO,loginSaga)   //notwork
}
```

One different is the worked method have reducer

```
const initState = {
  user: undefined,
};
const User = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionList.SET_USER:
      const {user} = action;
      return {...state,user};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default User;
```

But my method have none,(i thoght data was save in state action)

Comment: why `const getJsonData = JSON.stringify(getJson)` ? try with `const getJsonData = getJson`

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it not work, it **already** return `[object][object]` at `getJson`, it show on `console.log`

Comment: did i format json wrong?

Comment: replace `console.log('GetJson '+getJson)` with `console.log(getJson)` . If you concat json with a string u will always get GETJson[object][object]

Comment: or u can use this `console.log('GetJson ', getJson)`

Comment: yes, it work !! the json is working, but how can i return username? it have this format https://ibb.co/b1CrgnF

Comment: and return undifined when i try to access username

Comment: and for playground example you can follow this link https://codesandbox.io/s/48jl7?file=/src/App.js

```axios.get(url).then(response => {console.log(response.data);});```

Comment: Other than this, I believe that there are multiple mistakes here. If you are doing this for testing purposes then its fine. But if u are doing it for any production level projects then you are playing with fire. The password here is not hashed. Secondly you should not be checking passwords like this.

Comment: Ah i just learing react-native, so it just local auth, it will check input and compare to json file, if that match, log in, otherwise, it not

Answer (score 2):

`console.log('GetJson ' + getJson);` You're printing a concatenation of strings and objects. Modify it to `console.log('GetJson ',  getJson);`

Besides, you should return the `res.data` from `axios.get()` method, see [Response Schema](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema). You will get the plain object of JavaScript, there is no need to use `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export function requestGetUser() {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/khanh21011999/demo/user',
  }).then((res) => res.data);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, i see weird result with json, and i got it! res.data will return data, but without that, it return all data contain `data` also